# Can I add Mapbox data (markers) to CartoDB basemap

Tags: carto, mapbox

I have prepared a basemap in Mapbox which includes imported data (basically, marker points). I was expecting these markers to show when using that project as a basemap in CartoDB, but it only shows the basic tiles. Is anyone aware of this issue or how I could go about including the markers from Mapbox in CartoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a Mapbox basemap in CartoDB, tiles are all you're bringing in.  CartoDB has no concept of the underlying data you used to build your basemap, it only knows how to access the tiles, which are pictures made using that data.

It sounds like you want to use CartoDB's wizards to style your points and add interactivity to the map.  The only way to do this is to load the marker data into your CartoDB account.

Another option is to use leaflet (via cartodb.js or mapbox.js) to render and style the markers client-side.

Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Thank you, that increases my understanding of Mapbox and how other programmes interact with it - I had assumed, wrongly, that I was creating the entire basemap to be brought in via CartoDB. 

I had two sets of data: the static location 'points' and then the measures to display on top of that, but separate from those points.

What I think I will do is upload the data I had previously on Mapbox to CartoDB and combine to the same map using layers as you suggest.